# Can't fix broken dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, dependencies

I have the following dependency problem which I couldn't fix using any direct approach or by using any of the proposed solutions from similar problems.

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpango-1.0-0 : Breaks: libpango1.0-0:i386 (< 1.32.5-2) but 1.30.0-1 is installed
libpango1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libcairo2:i386 (>= 1.8.10-3) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.31.8) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libthai0:i386 (>= 0.1.12) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not installed
                    Depends: libxft2:i386 (> 2.1.1) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libxrender1:i386 but it is not installed
libpangocairo-1.0-0 : Breaks: libpango1.0-0:i386 (< 1.32.5-2) but 1.30.0-1 is installed
libpangoft2-1.0-0 : Breaks: libpango1.0-0:i386 (< 1.32.5-2) but 1.30.0-1 is installed
libpangoxft-1.0-0 : Breaks: libpango1.0-0:i386 (< 1.32.5-2) but 1.30.0-1 is installed
staruml : Depends: libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0) but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Also, I get the following message from the software center.

```
Software index is broken This is a major failure of your software management system. Please check for broken packages with synaptic, check the file permissions and correctness of the file '/etc/apt/sources.list' and reload the software information with: 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get install -f'.
```

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get autoremove, apt-get clean, apt-get autoclean` ?

Comment: Yes i did. none of them seem to work.